# Parallax scroll speed not working after first instance

Tags: javascript, jquery, parallax

I'm trying to make an overlapping image grid where each image has a different scroll speed.
My problem is that it stops working after the first div. I'm stumped.

INDEX

```
<div class="news-item first-col" data-scroll-speed="2">
    <img src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_directory'); ?>/imgs/w.jpg" ;>


    </div>
    <div class="news-item second-col" data-scroll-speed=“2”>
    <img src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_directory'); ?>/imgs/hopper 1.jpg" ;>

    </div>
    <div class="news-item third-col" data-scroll-speed=“3”>
    <img src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_directory'); ?>/imgs/final_07.jpg" ;/>

    </div>
    <div class="news-item fourth-col" data-scroll-speed=“5”>
    <img src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_directory'); ?>/imgs/modernegyromace2.jpg" ;/>

    </div>

    <div class="news-item fifth-col" data-scroll-speed=“10”>
    <img src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_directory'); ?>/imgs/Geisha In Car copy-Recovered.jpg" ;/>

    </div>

    <div class="news-item sixth-col" data-scroll-speed=“3”>
    <img src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_directory'); ?>/imgs/web8.jpg" ;/>

    </div>

    <div class="news-item seventh-col" data-scroll-speed=“11”>
    <img src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_directory'); ?>/imgs/hamda_film_final_003.jpg" ;/>

    </div>

    <div class="news-item eighth-col" data-scroll-speed=“1”>
    <img src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_directory'); ?>/imgs/CNV00043.jpg" ;/>

    </div>

    <div class="news-item ninth-col" data-scroll-speed=“2”>
    <img src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_directory'); ?>/imgs/fianl_008.jpg" ;/>

    </div>

    <div class="news-item ten-col" data-scroll-speed=“4”>
    <img src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_directory'); ?>/imgs/dimensions_2015023.jpg" ;/>

    </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
(function ($) {
var myBoxes = $('.news-item'); // Populate an array with our three boxes,    identified by class
$(window).scroll(function () {
var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
myBoxes.each(function () {
    var $this = $(this); // Grab current box object
    var scrollspeed = parseInt($this.data('scroll-speed')), // Grab the data-scroll-speed value and parse into Integer 
        offset = -scrollTop / scrollspeed;
    // The offset gives minus value of scrollTop divided by scrollspeed
    $this.css('transform', 'translateY(' + offset + 'px)');
    // Attaches a CSS transform to translate/move the element up the Y axis by our offset value as we scroll
});
});
)(jQuery);
```

CSS

```
news-item { max-width: 200px; height: 500px; position: absolute; }

    .news-item img {
    height: 100%;
    }

    .first-col {
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    }

    .second-col {
    left: 300px;
    top: 250px;
    }

    .third-col {
    top: 100px;
    left: 1000px;
    }

    .fourth-col {
    top: 600px;
    left: 50px;
    }

    .fifth-col {
    top: 900px;
    left: 300px;
    }

    .sixth-col {
    top: 1200px;
    left: 350px;
    }

    .seventh-col {
    top: 1400px;
    left: 650px;
    }
```

Comment: First thing i notice is that you are using `.data`  wrong, when your attribute looks like this `data-scroll-speed` to access it using `.data` you need to type `.data('scrollSpeed')`, check https://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: It's your funky quotation marks on the `data-scroll-speed` that start at the second item. They'll cause `parseInt` to fail.  You're using [this](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=201C) but it should be [this](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=22).

Comment: of course! thanks, changing the "" worked!